# Spinner listener to change activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback

I have a tabbed activity that has a spinner in its Toolbar. I need to trigger changes in the tab fragments whenever the spinner value changes.

I have so far implemented it by getting the cropsSpinner instance from the Fragment. However it's not working as needed. I am new to listeners; is there a way I can do this with Android callbacks?

**ExtensionActivity.java**

```
public class ExtensionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
    @BindView(R.id.container) ViewPager mViewPager;
    @BindView(R.id.tabs) TabLayout tabLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.spinner_nav) public Spinner cropsSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_extension);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter  = new SectionsPageAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new ExtDescFragment(),"Description");
        adapter.addFragment(new ExtLandPFragment(),"Land Preparation");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

**ExtDescFragment.java**

```
public class ExtDescFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ext_desc, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        ((ExtensionActivity)getActivity()).cropsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CROP =((ExtensionActivity)getActivity()).cp.get(position);
                Log.e("CROP",CROP);
                getCropInf();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did onItemSelected() and onNothingSelected() get called when you select an item of cropperSpinner?

Comment: The items get selected but i need all the fragments to detect this change so i was wondering if i can create a listener for when the spinner value changes and implement it in all the fragments

Comment: So you have different tabs and you have spinner in each tab and you want if you change the data inside the spinner then it should reflect in other fragments too. Am i getting right ?

Comment: No i have one spinner in the Tabbed Activity, whose change i need to reflect in its Fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your additional info I suggest you let your `cropperSpinner` **private** and using **list custom listener** like:

```
interface OnCropperSpinnerSelectedListener {
    void onItemSelected(int pos);
}
```

Then store a list of listener in **ExtensionActivity**:

```
List<OnCropperSpinnerSelectedListener> listeners;
```

after that write a setter method to add listener to the listener list:

```
void addCropperSpinnerSelectedListener(OnCropperSpinnerSelectedListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}
```

Then, you have to implement OnItemSelectedListener in **ExtensionActivity**:

```
cropsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
                       listeners.get(i).onItemSelected(position);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
});
```

Finally, when you want any Fragment to listen to spinner value changes event (Eg: **ExtDescFragment**), just call the method `addCropperSpinnerSelectedListener()` inside `onCreate()` of this fragment and implement your own logic.

**Explain**: So every time user select item on spinner, the `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` will call `onItemSelected()`, here we loop through our custom listener list that have connection to fragments and call our `onItemSelected(int pos)` to notify all fragment.